# How to set a table width programmatically in JSP?

Tags: html, css, jsp, width

```
<table border="0">
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            Header
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${Results != null}">
        <table border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>
                    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                </td>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
                </td>
                <td>
                    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

As shown above, the first table with "Header" always appear but the second table doesn't appear all the time, it depending on `${Results != null}`.

When second table is appear, the width is depending on the content. Now I wondering how to set the width of my first table, so that the width follow second table's width.

Comment: one solution is you can wrap second table inside first table [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypvmu8wd/)

Comment: you can assign ids both the tables and inside the condition write below script to set the width of first table `<script>document.getElementById("table1").style.width=document.getElementById("table2").style.offsetWidth;</script>`